# Will a 3rd Generation Intel i-5 CPU work with 2nd generation mobo?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I was wondering, as the title says, will a 2nd gen intel motherboard work with 3rd gen intel i-5 processor? The sockets are the same but I wasnt sure. I have not upgraded or built a machine in a while and im a little out of the loop.

Thanks!

Comment: What motherboard and what CPU? There's no way to know without the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

By default, it doesn't work. You must do a BIOS update. And there's the catch... Google IF the producer of that motherboard offer a BIOS update. Some do, some don't.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here are some links for mobo and cpu: http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8H61M/     http://ark.intel.com/products/53445/Intel-Core-i5-2310-Processor-(6M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz) ... ill do some research from Radoo comments. Thanks everyone! Sorry I fail at using this site.

Comment: I think im just going to go with 2nd gen processor. From what Radoo said, it sounds like I would have to have a 2nd gen to boot up in order to get to the bios, then firmware update, and swap processors. Am I wrong?

Comment: It seems like your MB has a BIOS update for 3rd generation of Intel Core processors. You're right. You need a Sandy Bridge (2nd generation) first to upgrade the BIOS, then swap with the newer Sandy Bridge CPU. If you plan using the GPU on the micro-processor, I'd recommend getting the Ivy Bridge; there's quite a difference between Intel HD 3000 and  Intel HD 4000. You could borrow a Sandy Bridge from a friend...

Comment: Thank you, Radoo. I tried to vote for your comment but it keeps telling me I have to log in. I registered and tried again but its not happening.

Answer (score 0):

A BIOS update is needed for the board to recognise the new chips and boot successfully. Most motherboard manufacturers made said updates available though i'm sure there are exceptions out there.

If you are upgrading a machine then this is generally no problem. You just run the BIOS update before you start work on the hardware upgrades.

If you are building a machine from second hand parts, repairing a machine that is belived to have a failed CPU or for some strange reason have chosen to buy obsolete parts new-old-stock this can be more of a problem because you can get into a catch 22 situation where you can't boot the board to apply the BIOS update unless you have an older CPU to hand.